# Azure DevOps API: get all testcase steps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to get all the testcase steps data via Azure DevOps API?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution:

```
GET https://{host}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{plan id}/Suites/{suite id}/TestCase/{testcase id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this particular Endpoing,

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0
```

and access [TestActionResultModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#testactionresultmodel)

Comment: Could you suggest how to link the runs to testcase id?

Comment: i dont think you can do that with single API call

Comment: Some testcases points contain zero value for `lastTestRun` and `lastResult` because never ran, but they still contain the steps. So the question is how to access the steps for this case?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I am not going to access it with a single call

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps api has endpoints for returning test runs, results and cases. The api is wrapped in a PowerShell module called [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS) that has functions like

- Get-APTestSuiteList
- Get-APTestRunList
- Get-APTestRun
- Get-APTestRunStatistic
- Get-APTestResultList
- Get-APTestResult
- Get-APTestPlanList

The following command will return a list of all your test cases in a suite.

`Get-APTestSuiteList -Session 'youSessionName'`

Be sure to setup a session locally with `New-APSession` when first installing the module. You can find the session documentation [here](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS#managing-session-data).